# No API Request Triggered on Login in Next.js Application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js project and facing an issue where no request is made to my API when trying to log in, and I'm unable to determine why this is happening. Below is the structure of my project and the relevant code.

[image: Folder structure]

Issue:

I have a login component located at `src/app/login/page.js`, where I'm trying to perform a login operation by sending a POST request to my API when a button is clicked. However, it seems that no request is being made, or at least, it's not reaching my API.

Login Component **(src/app/login/page.js)**:

```
    const buttonClicked = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const result = await fetch('/api/authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            }),
        });

        if (result.error) {
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    };
```

and in my `pages\api\authenticate.js` i have below

```
const authenticate = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        console.log(process.env.API_URL);
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/login`, {
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
            });

            const { token, user } = response.data;

            res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('auth_token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development', // Secure in production
                maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 1 month (60 seconds, 60 minutes, 24 hours, 30 days)
                sameSite: 'strict', // can be 'strict' or 'lax'
                path: '/',
            }));

            res.status(200).json({ user, message: 'Authentication successful' });
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' });
        }
    } else {
        // Handle any other HTTP method
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
        res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
};

export default authenticate;
```

I should also add that in my browzer console, i get the error beloe

```
page.js:36 
POST http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate 404 (Not Found)

Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

**Questions:**

- Why is no request being made to my API when the login button is
  clicked?

Note: The reason I use both the app router and pages router at the same time is the documentation adviced that

Comment: What does your JSX look like where the `buttonClicked` function is called?

Comment: the button clicks as expected, and i added the console errors to show that it was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `pages`, `public` and `src` folders must be in parallel. In your case `pages` in inside `src` which is making your endpoints not discoverable hence the 404.

I tried your code with few tweaks to hit the API and it worked. Here is the code.

```
const authenticate = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    console.log('process.env.API_URL');

  } else {
    // Handle any other HTTP method
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
};

export default authenticate;
```

And this is the output

```
process.env.API_URL
```

Hope this helps. I am using Nextjs 12.